# Is there a way to have an encrypted folder on macOS with fast read/write operations?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, disk-utility, encryption, data-transfer

I've tried and used Disk Utility to create an encrypted image, so I can store data in it securely. However, when I tried to write files to this image, the write operation was too slow (to write ~50 GB of data, it would take 1 day as estimated).

My question: is there a robust alternative that allows creating an encrypted space in the hard disk to store data with fast read/write operations?

**Device :**

Apple MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2012)

- Processor : 2.6 GHz Intel Core i7
- Memory : 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
- Hard drive : APPLE HDD HTS547575A9E384

  - Rotational Rate:  5400
  - Partition Map Type:   GPT (GUID Partition Table)
- OS version : 10.12.1

I am transferring data to an encrypted image on the hard drive. Its encryption type is 128-bit AES.

**Source of data**

The external hard drive that I am transferring data from : StoreJet Transcend Media.

- Partition Map Type : GPT (GUID Partition Table)
- Encrypted. Encryption Type : AES-XTS

Comment: USB 3 can do 640MB/s, but a 5400 drive probably at best 100MB/s. Additional factor would be how full the HD is & how fragmented. 50GB of free contiguous space would be unusual on a 4-year-old 750GB boot drive.

Comment: I'd suggest replacing your internal HDD with an SSD. This will not only speed up your data transfer rate but help speed up everything you do on the computer.